# Qt - RegExp not working properly

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am working in Qt 5.2.1. I need to write a regular expression that will find strings that represent numbers that have decimal values, e.g. it would find 1.234 or 123.4, but not 123 or something like a1.2. I have this regular expression:

```
QRegExp r("^\\d+\.\\d+$");
```

However I've noticed that in addition to finding values that it should, it also finds any value that is all digits and has >= 3 digits but no decimal, e.g. 12345, and values that are all digits except for one character in the middle, such as 12:345. I'm pretty sure the issue is from the regexp trying to use "." to represent any character, but I thought using "." was supposed to make it recognize the actual "." character instead. If anyone sees what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QString txt = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
QRegExp r("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+");
QRegExp r("^\\d+\\.\\d+$");//with this \\. works properly too (same output)

if(txt.contains(r))
{
    qDebug() << txt << "contains double" ;
}
else
    qDebug() << txt << " not contains double" ;
```

On my computer it catches number with decimal point and ignore others.

Output:

```
"45:3"  not contains double 
"45.323" contains double 
"12345"  not contains double 
"12:345"  not contains double
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I changed it to `"\\."` and it works now. However, could you please explain *why* that works? If backslash is used to escape special characters, it seems to me like `"\."` should escape the special character `"."` and just look for the period character, while `"\\."` would escape `"\"` while keeping `"."` special, so it would find `"\"` followed by any character. Why does it work the second way but not the first?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls yes, `"\\"` escapes `"\"` so "\\." is escaped `"\"plus. == \.` It seems that you use simple dot. As documentation said: `. (dot) Matches any character (including newline).` I play with your first regexp and I get `45:3` , `45b3` and `45\n3` returns true, it means that it was `dot`, not what you nedd.